# sbt new scala/scalatest.g8 fails on TransportException

Tags: scala, sbt

When I try to create the ScalaTest example with this command:

```
sbt new scala/scalatest-example.g8 fails on TransportException
```

I get the following:

```
[info] Set current project to scala (in build file:/Users/chasrmartin/Dropbox/Etudes/Scala/)
[error] org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@github.com:scala/scalatest-example.g8.git: Auth fail
[error]     at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:139)
[error]     at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:193)
```

I've tried several workarounds from around the next (eg [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465656/helloworld-example-sbt-new-sbt-scala-seed-g8-not-working)) to no avail. It would seem this has to be a simple problem, I got this command from a beginners tutorial.

**Update**

I got this command from https://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started-sbt-track/testing-scala-with-sbt-on-the-command-line.html

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I've searched at Scala repo https://github.com/scala and they don't have this scalatest.g8 nor scalatest-example.g8. Are you sure it's from scala?

Comment: Are you trying to get this one? https://github.com/bernhard-42/scala-test.g8

Comment: See above, it's from an example at scala-lang.org.

Comment: reported at https://github.com/scala/scala-lang/issues/755

Comment: Thank you. It appears to be an auth problem.

Comment: It's not an auth problem, the repo simply doesn't exist

Comment: Okay. Might be useful to have it say "no such repo" instead of sending people down the transport path. I spent probably 4 hours trying to figure out why my github ssh had stopped working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This project doesn't seems to exists anymore. 
Instead I would prefer to run with the normal **scala-seed.g8**

```
> sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8
```

And add the test classes manually.
[This](https://scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started-intellij-track/testing-scala-in-intellij-with-scalatest.html) is an equivalent tutorial with the same classes and tests.

The scala seed template already comes with the structure you want, with the test dependency. You can run `sbt test` normally.

Comment: Just typed

`sbt new scala/scalatest-example.g8`

and it worked