# Connection to https://repo1.maven.org refused when sbt new

Tags: scala, maven, playframework, sbt, jgit

I want to create a new project framework play with tools sbt.

First I had the same problem of the topic [HelloWorld example (sbt new sbt/scala-seed.g8) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465656/helloworld-example-sbt-new-sbt-scala-seed-g8-not-working) and adding the code `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://` resolved the error.

But now I have the error follow : "Unknown exception: Connection to https://repo1.maven.org refused" when I launch the command `sbt new playframework/play-java-seed.g8`.
I configured the sbtconfig file with parameters proxy but not change.

I try again with the command line `sbt.bat new https://github.com/playframework/play-java-seed.g8` but not change.

I use sbt 1.0.4 and Windows 10.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If by chance you are working from behind a proxy, you may want to have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803459/how-to-use-sbt-from-behind-proxy

Comment: I tried a lot of proposition of your link but no change ...

Comment: When I try with `sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8` it's working but not when I try with `sbt new playframework/play-java-seed.g8`. But me I want to create a project play java....